# Export CloudFormation file from CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Since I've seen Hashicorp Terraform, I have been wondering why the "plan" it can export has binary format.

Now in the AWS world you have got a declarative configuration language called CloudFormation which can be abstracted from using AWS CDK (Cloud Development Kit) in a common programming language of your choice.

Therefore my question: imagine somebody familiar with CloudFormation would like to see what CDK code will do. Is there a way to export a CloudFormation file using CDK?

Comment: So from your experience there's no way to export CF file from terraform code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: in the [hello world CDK example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/hello_world.html), they call it "synthesizing":

`cdk synth`

^^ produces CloudFormation file.

Comment: The only problem is that sometimes `synth` requires online access (if your lambda is in VPC).

Answer (score 0):

As Tamara had already mentioned, CDK already produces this for you during synthesis. To clarify this further, if you look in the **cdk.out** directory, you'll find a *xxxxx.template.json* file for every stack.

This is your synthesized template that CDK passes onto Cloudformation.

Additionally, you may also benefit from taking a look at [cdk diff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-diff).

> The cdk diff command compares the current version of a stack defined in your app with the already-deployed version, or with a saved AWS CloudFormation template, and displays a list of changes.

Let me know if you have any further questions!